# Java maintain insertion order AND duplicated values

Tags: java, data-structures

So i am having a big problem with java because i cant find a structure thath will maintain the insertion order AND the duplicates!!

```
    LinkedList<Character> queue2 = new LinkedList<Character>();
    LinkedHashSet<Character> queue3 = new LinkedHashSet<Character>();
    while (!queue2.isEmpty()) {
        char k= queue2.getLast();
        queue3.add(k);
        queue2.remove(queue2.getLast());
    }
```

Comment: Set implementations doesn't allow duplicates, use List as in `queue2`.

Answer (score 1):

[`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) implementations maintain the order and the duplicates by definition. You can thus use `LinkedList`, `ArrayList`, `Vector`... For both `queue2` and `queue3`